# Paypal Get User Info from REST API

Tags: paypal

I am building a Login that uses "Login with PayPal button". 
and uses the generated button: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/

After getting the user's consent, I wants to get the user email address. 
the web runs without error, however, I only gets User Id. others are null.

I did the example from the document: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#get-user-information

what are the right steps to get the user information?

Thank you.

Comment: Which scopes did you choose when generating the LIPP button?

Did you set the correct clientId when generating the button?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code example on https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/ruby?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

As you can see there is a scope defined as

`:scope => "openid email"`

Most probably you missed `email` in your code.

Comment: I have a "scope not valid" error message, could you help me ?